# Get only numbers at the end (regex)

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I'd like to get **only** the numbers (integers) at the **end** of the phrases below:

```
VISTA AES TIETE E UNT N2 600 
VISTA IT AUUNIBANCO PN N1 1.400
OPCAO DE VENDA 04/21 COGNP450ON 4,50COGNE 100.000
```

I mean: 600, 1400, 100000. I'll add each one of them to a database later.

I tried to use regex: (?<=\s)(\d*\s*)|(\d*.\d*)$

But it didn't work properly. Any ideas?

PS: We use dots, not commas to represent a thousand: 1.000, instead of 1,000.

Comment: Why `100000` in the expected OP but not `100.000`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the pattern that you tried, this part `(?<=\s)(\d*\s*)` matches optional digits, followed by optional whitespace chars while there must be a whitespace char directly to the left.

That will also get all the positions in the string where there is a whitspace char to the left, as the digits and the whitespace char in the match are optional.

In this part `(\d*\.\d*)$` the digits are optional, so it could also match just a dot at the end of the string.

---

If there has to be a whitespace char before the number at the end, you can use:

```
(?<=\s)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=\s)` Positive lookbehind, assert a whitspace char to the left from the current position
- `\d{1,3}` Match 1-3 digits
- `(?:\.\d{3})*` Optionally repeat a dot and 3 digits
- `$` End of string

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IDFC6M/1).

If the number can also be by itself, you could assert a whitespace boundary to the left `(?<!\S)`

```
(?<!\S)\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*$
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZY7ddu/1).

For example, using `str.extract` and wrapping the pattern in a capture group:

```
import pandas as pd

strings = [
    "VISTA AES TIETE E UNT N2 600",
    "VISTA IT AUUNIBANCO PN N1 1.400",
    "OPCAO DE VENDA 04/21 COGNP450ON 4,50COGNE 100.000"
]

df = pd.DataFrame(strings, columns=["colName"])
df['lastNumbers'] = df['colName'].str.extract(r"(?<=\s)(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{3})*)$")

print(df)
```

Output

```
                                             colName lastNumbers
0                       VISTA AES TIETE E UNT N2 600         600
1                    VISTA IT AUUNIBANCO PN N1 1.400       1.400
2  OPCAO DE VENDA 04/21 COGNP450ON 4,50COGNE 100.000     100.000
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually for your use case, I don't think you'd even need `regex`

You can just split the strings and take the last one, and replace dot by empty string

If it's dataframe (since you have tagged `Pandas`),

```py
> df['colName'].str.split().str[-1].str.replace('.', '')
0       600
1      1400
2    100000
Name: colName, dtype: object
```

If it's list of strings

```py
> list(map(lambda x: x.replace('.', ''),map(lambda x: x.split()[-1], data)))
['600', '1400', '100000']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l = ["VISTA AES TIETE E UNT N2 600",
"VISTA IT AUUNIBANCO PN N1 1.400",
"OPCAO DE VENDA 04/21 COGNP450ON 4,50COGNE 100.000"]
```

If the data is in the form of dataframe.

```
df=DataFrame({
    'col':l
})
df.col.str.extract('(\d*\.*\d*)?$').astype(str).replace('\.','', regex=True)
```

**Output**

```
0   600
1   1400
2   100000
```